# Colorbox displays image as binary data

Tags: javascript, image, backbone.js, binary, base64

I'm trying to use [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) for a website build using [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/). I've got a simple image tag like this:

```
<a class="gallery" href="/document/123"><img class="attachment-preview" src="/document/123" /></a>
```

The url /document/123 displays the (simple png) image. 123 is the id of the image, and the server gets the base64 encoded image from the DB, decodes it, and displays it. When I put in example.com/document/123 in the browser it displays the image correctly, and the image is also correctly displayed with the tag I pasted above.

When I then click the image however, the colorbox opens and only shows what I guess is binary data:

```
�wQH*��:�R��hc�:+{�����d��j���}7u($��@�����[�6Ym}���^(_�i�~�H�>�� etc..
```

So my question are: how can this be? And more importantly: how can I solve it? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Colorbox will automatically detect the content type of the href target by the extension name of url. For example, color box will display content as image if url target is a file with .jpg, .png or .gif extension. Url "/document/123" will be treated as html content even through it returns a image.

You could solve this issue by adding photo: true attribute when you initialze the colorbox plugin.

```
$("a").colorbox({photo:true});
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]